# How can i print an ascii with a for loop?

Tags: python, ascii

Im trying to make a program that draws an ascii for me, and bc im lazy to make it with a raw string, im making it with a for loop, and i wrote this programs

```
import os
import random as rand
import time
from termcolor import colored

def cls():
  os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
cls()

characters = [
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d",
  "e",
  "f",
  "g",
  "h",
  "i",
  "j",
  "k",
  "l",
  "m",
  "n",
  "o",
  "p",
  "q",
  "r",
  "s",
  "t",
  "u",
  "v",
  "w",
  "x",
  "y",
  "@",
  "#",
  "$",
  "&",
  "+",
  "(",
  ")",
  "/",
  "\"",
  "\'",
  "!",
  "?",
]

width = 10
height = 0

chars = []

#for i in range(300):
    #white = rand.choice(characters)
    #red = colored(rand.choice(characters), 'red')
    #cls()
    #print((white * 300) + (red * 300))
print(rand.choice(characters)*300)
```

And this is what it shows:

```
))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Or

```
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Or some random characters from the `characters` variable

And this is what i want i want it to show

```
Jhgakl+-&;#)9);$)"((@jhhkakllsb)))(+-@(+$8+!$;;"(#;))));;#+$!"+!#iajnsnnan($!(#!!#?#??#(!#oiiooqoojndnnna(((njakkakmsl(!;?#///bbjkakakKkxjbxjskakl(+;)))#/)(;$((@(
```

Im trying to make an ascii art with python, can someone help me with this pls?

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.choices` instead of `random.choice`, or use loops:

```
print(''.join(rand.choices(character, k=300)))
print(''.join(rand.choice(character) for _ in range(300)))
```